# How to move 1 variable from a class to another class

Tags: c#

The issue with this program is that after running the Data class to move the target variable over to the Program class, so It can be used in the  mean calculation.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[,] array1 = new int[3, 3]
            { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
        double mean = 0;
    
        Data Datacollection = new Data();            


        //This is where I want the target variable from the data class
        mean = (double) 1800 / target;

        
        Console.WriteLine("The amount of numbers with 2 digits are {0} in a 1800 data graph", target);
        Console.WriteLine("With a mean of {0} in 1800",mean.ToString("0.00"));
        
    }
}



class Data
{

    private int[,] array1 = new int[3, 3]
        { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };

    private int target = 0;
    
    public Data(int Datacollection)
    {            
        Random RandNum = new Random();

        for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {

                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                {
                    array1[i, j] = RandNum.Next(0, 5000);
                    Console.Write(" {0} ", array1[i, j]);

                    if (array1[i, j] < 99)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Required data type and required fields found, Data colleted");

                        target = target + 1;
                        
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }            
        }           
    }
}
```

Comment: use `private static int target = 0;` and call `Data.target` everywhere you want.

Comment: "use private ... and call .... everywhere you want. " private is private... and will only be accessible inside the class `Data`

Comment: @majidhajibaba If it's `private`, you _cannot_ "call Data.target everywhere you want". And even if you could, you shouldn't.

Comment: Sorry guys! There was a mistake! you must also use a `public static` methods to `set` and `get` this private variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the ways to get target variable from `Data` class to the main method,

1. Create a property called target in Data class, assign value to it and read value from that property in main method.

   ```
   public class Data
   {

      public int Target { get; set; } = 0;

      public Data(int Datacollection)
      { 
         .... 

         this.Target++; //instead of target = target + 1
      }
   ```

Now use it in `Main()` method,

```
public  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    
    Data Datacollection = new Data();            


    mean = (double) 1800 / Datacollection.Target;

 ...   
}
```

2. Write separate function in `Data` class, return target value to the caller.

   ```
   public int CalculateTarget()
   {
    int[,] array1 = new int[3, 3]{ { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
    int target = 0;
    Random RandNum = new Random();

    for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                array1[i, j] = RandNum.Next(0, 5000);
                Console.Write(" {0} ", array1[i, j]);
                if (array1[i, j] < 99)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Required data type and required fields found, Data colleted");

                    target++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
     return target;     
   }
   ```

Now Call this method in your `Main()` function,

```
public  static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ...
    
    Data Datacollection = new Data();            

    //Call here
    var target = Datacollection.CalculateTarget();
    mean = (double) 1800 / target;

 ...   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should rather create a method that calculates what you need and **returns** the value instead of doing the calculation inside the constructor:

```
public int CalculateTarget()
{

    int[,] array1 = new int[3, 3]
        { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };
    int target = 0;
    Random RandNum = new Random();

    for (int m = 0; m < 200; m++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                array1[i, j] = RandNum.Next(0, 5000);
                Console.Write(" {0} ", array1[i, j]);

                if (array1[i, j] < 99)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Required data type and required fields found, Data colleted");

                    target = target + 1;
                    
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }        
    }
    return target;
}
```

Then you can call the method in your main:

```
    //This is where I want the target variable from the data class
    int targetFromData = Datacollection.CalculateTarget();
    mean = (double) 1800 / targetFromData;
```

A method yields the advantage that it can communicate/document its purpose via its name. If someone else will use your `Data` object, then it will not be obvious that there is some magic calculation going on already when the object is instantiated